# How to create a working ViewPager App?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-viewpager

I am trying to develop an application which would be a lot better if it had a clean ViewPagerUI. I dont need fancy menus (yet), all I want is that if I start my application It starts out as one relative Layout, and i can then swipe left and right to view two more Relative Layouts.

I have read, watched and studied tons and tons of tutorials in the past week, but they all seem to either be outdated, don't fit my needs (because they create new "pages" with a while/for loop, which is **definetely not** what i'm looking for), or are way to complicated/ leave out important information( i am a fresh developer, but I really don't want to give up) like the official guide on the android developers webpage.

I get that experienced developers can get a lot out of these tutorials, but I don't find them to be very informative for beginners/newbs.

Questions I asked myself while reading different guides are:

*Which differernt java classes/ xml files do I need to create, and which code goes where?*

*How does the ViewPager know which Fragment I want to display on any page?*

*How can I add working, "connected" code to all three fragments?*

To give you some helpful information:

- The first page should display a chart
- The second page contains edit texts, which add items to an array and thus to the chart on the first page on button click
- The third page contains settings for the chart

I don't need **ANY** other pages/activities/main menus whatsoever. Only these three interacting pages. 
I`ve found it to be the best option to go with relative layouts.
The second page should be the main page.

I am sorry if you think that my issue is dumb, but i am trying to create this app for over a week now, and i seem to not get any traction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I have read, watched and studied tons and tons of tutorials in the past week" -- why didn't you read a book? "are way to complicated/ leave out important information... like the official guide on the android developers webpage" -- you will have better luck on Stack Overflow if you explain what you tried and what specific problems you encountered. As it stands, your "question" is basically asking us to write your code for you (as anything shorter than that would "leave out important information").

Comment: I understand you. Which books can you recommend, seeing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: In general, I recommend books that have been published within the past two years, as Android changes frequently. And the reason I recommend books (or courses) is because they are structured to teach you in an organized fashion. If you try learning by watching random tutorial videos, you get a random education. :-) In terms of specific books, I am rather biased, as [I have one](https://commonsware.com/Android).

Comment: Viewpager is just a way of displaying fragments side by side, so number of pages you need is the number of fragments and the in your main layout create a viewpager and set it attributes to match parents and in the main activity class find the viewpager and then you need to apply and adapter that does all the job for you.  For the adapter create a new class and extend fragmentstatepageradapter and in the in its get count specifiy the number of fragment and in its getitem method return the fragment at appropriate position using the position parameter and thats its

Comment: Thank you nikhil, that helped a lot